# Обстоятельство или дополнение?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> Я говорю по-английски.

Не могу понять: "по-английски" — дополнение или обстоятельство?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*По-английски* в этом предложении является обстоятельством образа действия, отвечающим на вопрос "как?".

Чтобы отличать дополнения от обстоятельств, запомните: дополнения отвечают на вопросы всех падежей, кроме именительного (что? чего? кого? кем? чем? кому? чему? о чем? о ком?). Если же от глагола задается другой вопрос, вы имеете дело не с дополнением.